# Create a method for intersection points

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, morphic

http://paulbourke.net/geometry/2circle/ 
Solved this with help of few people on here, This code will get the point of intersection for two circles

Here is my workspace code

```
    |b b1 r r1 r2 d |
    b1:= CircleAnimeMorph  new.   " CircleAnimeMorph is my new   class"
    b1 center: 100@100.
    b1 openInWorld.
    b:= CircleAnimeMorph  new.
    b openInWorld.
    d:=  b1 center dist: b center. "distance between 2 circles"
    r:=b1 bounds  width /2.  "radius of first circle"
    r1:=b bounds width/2. "radius of second Circle"
    r2:=r + r1 .

    (d )< (r2)

    ifTrue: [| a h mid c c1 myPen  h1 h2 mx my mc mc1|

    a := (r squared - r1 squared + d squared) / (2 * d).
    h := (r squared - a squared) sqrt.
   h1:= b center y - b1 center y.
   h2:= b center x - b1 center x.  
  mx:=a * (b center x - b1 center x)/d.
  my:=a* (b center y  -   b1 center y)/d.

     mid := ((mx)+(b1 center x)  @ (b1 center y )+(my) )   " calculates mid point between 2 intersecting circles (p2)"
    {  
                  mc:=(h * h1)/d.
                  mc1:=(h * h2)/d.
                  c:=(mid x +  mc )@ (mid y - mc1 )."Actual Intersecting points"
                  c1:=(mid x -mc) @ (mid y + mc1 )."Actual Intersecting points"
                  Transcript show: (c); show: (c1); cr
    }.
                  myPen := Pen new.
                  myPen color: Color  red.
                  myPen  putDotOfDiameter: 5 at: mid.
                  myPen  putDotOfDiameter: 5 at: c1.
                  myPen  putDotOfDiameter: 5 at: c. ].
```

Can any one help me make this a methods ,I wanna make this a intersection method  which will do all this
when i say

```
    b1 intersection:b.
```

should do all of this and draw colored dots at intersecting points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to add a new method to your class. Open up a Browser, navigate to `CircleAnimeMorph`, click somewhere in the method category pane (that's the second pane from the right), click in the code pane (the lower half of the Browser) and add

```
intersection: aCircleAnimeMorph
    "And here, put your workspace code, but remove the initialisation stuff,
     change 'b' to 'self' and 'b1' to 'aCircleAnimeMorph',
     and make sure you actually return the values. Don't forget to remove
     the Transcript and drawing logic."
```

Comment: It looks like you miss some basics. Take a look at this video to see how to develop in pharo. http://vimeo.com/18520870

Comment: @Igor, of course you meant to put this comment on the question, not on this post  :)

Comment: yes. my comment was addressed to topic starter , of course, not you :)